# How to optimize the nested for loop having nested if else in python

Tags: python, optimization

```
l=[]
for index,value in df['Term'].iteritems():
    for i,v in df['Date'].iteritems():
        if index == i:
           if pd.isnull(value):
               l.append(None)
           else:
              value=int(value):
              l.append(v + relativedelta(months=+value)
```

This is taking a lot of time. Can someone please help me to optimize this function.

Comment: @JonSG it's a nested for loop, can't zip

Comment: @Bharel Ahh, I missed that, then maybe `itertools.product()` would help

Comment: @JonSG is probably not going to materially affect the runtime

Comment: For starters, *just don't use `iteritems`, ever*. Use `itertuples`. But what, exactly, is this code supposed to do? `if index == i:` implies you are trying to algiht everything by index, if so, why are you doing a nested loop?? Please always include a [mcve] with example inputs and desired outputs and a description of what you are actually trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Pandas that well, so my zip statement may not be perfect.

You only care about the items for which `i == index`, so this really is a zip statement.

```
l = []
for value, v in zip(df['Term'], df['Date']):
    if pd.isnull(value):
        l.append(None)
    else:
        value=int(value):
        l.append(v + relativedelta(months=+value)
```